# securing CORS: is there a security scheme with cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I have two web-servers responding on two different ports. I have the main web server that serves a website with a lot of javascript behind HTTP digest authentication, the secondary webserver only executes CGIs that can be directly accessed, always by using HTTP digest, or that can accessed with CORS by the ajax requests related to the main webserver. Both servers share the same users credentials.

My problem is that I don't want the browser to prompt for credentials when the javascript is making requests to the secondary webserver.

I came out with the idea that I could add some special header in the ajax request to the secondary web-server, and if this header is present I can ignore the HTTP authentication. Since the servers share the users credentials, if the user is able to log in into the main web-server, he'll be able to login into the second one as well.

Using a fixed header is of course useless. So the question is: is there a mechanism in CORS to tell the secondary webserver that the user is already authenticated in the first one? Something like a safe way to exchange tokens in cookies?

Comment: With AJAX request also send the token to 2nd server, there you can query 1st server to check if token is valid? CORS on second server must be enabled. Setting the cookie on server 1 won't help, cause it won't be accessible on 2nd server.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only the ports that are different cookies will be shared across these origins. So if you know for sure that a cookie is set once the user accesses origin 1, they will be included in requests to origin 2, as long as (assuming you're using `XMLHttpRequest`) `withCredentials` is set to true.

Now of course those cookies should contain some authentication data that you verify before you let them bypass HTTP authentication.

And hopefully you're using HTTPS so that the credentials are safe from network attackers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this has anything to do with CORS. What you need is a single-sign-on solution for the two different servers. You could implement a full-blown OAuth solution, or write a simple one yourself.

For a simple token-based authentication, you'd do the following:

1. When the user logs into your website, send down a expiring token (over SSL) that grants the user access to the web service.
2. Take the token and do a GET request to a non-authenticated endpoint in the web service. If the token is valid and non-expired, send an authentication token back to the browser.

As long as your web service implements HTTP authentication properly, the cookie will be set and the service calls won't prompt for credentials.

Comment: In order to make (2) GET request to second server while browsing 1st server, CORS must be enabled, or I do not follow you?

Comment: Sorry I think my wording was a bit confusing. Yes, CORS is something you need to deal with, but it sounded like you already solved your CORS issues. Even if you don't want to use CORS you could exchange the token in JSONP, hidden image, some other workaround. What I mean is you are really looking at a SSO solution, which works the same regardless of CORS or not. That said, it's true that since you're on the same domain your sites can share cookies. If that's not an option, let me know and I can expand on the answer.